# How to turn a Foreign key into Primary key and Row into Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable, datatables

I have a following table in a SQL Server database.

[image]

How can I remove the `OrderOptionId` and turn the `OrderNumer` as a unique key. (kind of pivot table) I want the above table to turn into as below.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a pivot query, not for a schema change:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        OrderNumber, OptionName, OptionValue 
    FROM OrdersTable
) AS t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(OptionValue)
    FOR OptionName IN ([Drink], [Sauce])
) AS pvt
```

See:

- [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on Microsoft Technet.
- [Simple Way To Use Pivot In SQL Query](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query) on CodeProject.
- [FROM (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) on Microsoft MSDN

Comment: Thanks Olivier, it worked perfectly but I forgot to mention about the ModifiedUtcDate column in the original table. I would like to get that column in Pivot table to so I can use the table for incremental load. I tried adding that column in your query but then the pivot table repeats the orderId multiple times. Would you be able to help with that?

Comment: See: [PIVOT on two or more fields in SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenobonn/2009/03/22/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 0):

Select only drinks, select only sauces, join them by `OrderNumber`.